# SoapHttpClientProtocol/HttpWebClientProtocol connection status

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, http, soap

I have a WebService reference (.NET CF 3.5) based on SoapHttpClientProtocol. My question is - is there a way to determine whether a connection to WebService is established other than calling a web method? Can I check at any time that the underlying connection is established and get its status?

Regards

Comment: Do you need to make this determination via code?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the communication state on the client.

```
using (XServiceSoapClient client = new XServiceSoapClient())
{
   client.State;
}

public enum CommunicationState
{
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates that the communication object has been instantiated and is configurable,
    //     but not yet open or ready for use.
    Created = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates that the communication object is being transitioned from the System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Created
    //     state to the System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened state.
    Opening = 1,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates that the communication object is now open and ready to be used.
    Opened = 2,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates that the communication object is transitioning to the System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Closed
    //     state.
    Closing = 3,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates that the communication object has been closed and is no longer
    //     usable.
    Closed = 4,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Indicates that the communication object has encountered an error or fault
    //     from which it cannot recover and from which it is no longer usable.
    Faulted = 5,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure no connection is made unless you call a method on the interface. Especially since the communication is HTTP-based.

In a project I was working on, I actually created a NOP method on the server that my client could call. I used that to determine if the supplied connection information and login credentials are valid (by using a try-catch block).